# Can half-shifted Were-Druids use all their powers?

Tags: dnd-4e

Normally, Druids can only use powers without the `Beast Form` keyword when in humanoid form, and only use powers with the `Beast Form` keyword when they use `Wild Shape` to transform into a beast. However, there are three Were themes (Werewolf, Werebear, Wererat) with a level 10 feature that specifies that you can assume a hybrid form and are not limited to using powers with the `Beast Form` keyword.

If a Druid takes the Werewolf theme and, at level 10, half-shifts into a hybrid form, are they then capable of using all their powers, both with and without the `Beast Form` keyword?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, you can.

That seems to be the basic reason those themes exist: to give a class like *Druid* some perks, but especially to give them the theme's level 10 ability to access *all their powers, all the time*.

### The detail of why it works that way

*I'll be quoting the Werewolf powers in this answer. The Werebear and Wererat have identically worded powers, except for being bears and dire rats rather than wolves.*

> **Beast Form:**  An effect type. A character can use a beast form power only while in beast form. Only certain characters can assume a beast form.

A Druid can cast their beast form powers from *any* beast form. There is nothing saying they can *only* cast those powers from their Wild Shape. They have their Wild Shape because they need a beast form to get at all their beast form powers - otherwise they would be a pretty silly class!

The Werebear/rat/wolf themes each come with a shape-changing power almost identical to the Druid's Wild Shape, except they're encounter powers rather than at-will:

> #### Wolf Shape
>
> Effect: **You change from your humanoid form to a beast form** — a wolf — that lasts until the end of the encounter. Alternatively, you can end the form as a minor action and shift 1 square. **While you are in beast form, you can’t use weapon or implement attack powers that lack the beast form keyword**, although you can sustain such powers.

This is a beast form, so now you can use beast form powers, except it prohibits you from using non-beast form powers! Note that using non-beast form powers is *only prohibited by the power* - it is not an inherent part of being in a beast form. At level 10, this limitation is removed:

> Werewolf Level 10 Feature (10th level): When you use the wolf shape power, you can assume the form of a humanoid-wolf hybrid, instead of a wolf. While in hybrid form, your equipment does not become part of your new form, and you are not forced to drop any items you are holding. **You are also not limited to using implement and weapon attack powers that have the beast form keyword.**

That effectively reduces the first paragraph of the Wolf Shape power to this:

> #### Wolf Shape
>
> Effect: **You change from your humanoid form to a beast form** — a wolf — that lasts until the end of the encounter. Alternatively, you can end the form as a minor action and shift 1 square.

Hey, there's no more limitation on powers without the beast form keyword now! You've reached the apex of your theme, and now you can be a humanoid wolf, dire rat or bear, and have access to powers both with and without the beast form keyword!

A pity it doesn't also apply to your Wild Shape.